# GEE error: 'Dictionary does not contain key: soil_moisture_am'

Tags: google-earth-engine, dictionary, mean, reduceregion

I am creating a FeatureCollection "randoms" that stores random points along with the field 'IDate', storing random times in milliseconds since 1970 (code below).

```
var randoms = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(table, 1297);
randoms = randoms.randomColumn('IDate');

var add_variables = function(feature) {
  var keepP = ['IDate'];
  var finalP = ee.Feature(feature.buffer(10000)).copyProperties(feature, keepP);
  var cur = ee.Number(feature.get('IDate'));
  var ne = ee.Number(1483228800000).add(cur.multiply(ee.Number(126124200000)));
  return finalP.set('IDate', ne);
}

randoms = randoms.map(add_variables);
print(randoms.first());
randoms = randoms.map(compute);
print(randoms.first());
```

I then map a function "compute" that finds the mean values of each field (e.g soil_moisture) for each feature (code bwlo).

```
var compute = function(feature) {
  var keepProperties = ['IDate'];
  
  var final = ee.Feature(feature).copyProperties(feature, keepProperties);
  var ccords = feature.geometry().centroid().coordinates();
  var initial_date = ee.Date(feature.get('IDate'));
  
  var start = ee.Number(ee.Feature(feature).get('IDate')).subtract(604800000);
  var lc_start = ee.Number(ee.Feature(feature).get('IDate')).subtract(31560000000);
  var end = ee.Number(ee.Feature(feature).get('IDate'));
  
  var geom = ee.Feature(feature).geometry();
  
  var smam = soilmoisture.filterDate(start, end).select('soil_moisture_am').mean();
  var ndvi = terrandvi.filterDate(start, end).select('NDVI').mean();
  var landc = landcover.filterDate(lc_start, end).select('LC_Prop1').mean();
  var elev = dem.select('be75');
  var aslope = ee.Terrain.products(elev).select(['aspect', 'slope']);
  var era5l = era5.filterDate(start, end).select(['dewpoint_temperature_2m', 'skin_temperature', 'total_precipitation_sum', 'u_component_of_wind_10m', 'v_component_of_wind_10m']).mean();
  
  var reduced_smam = smam.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: geom, scale: 9000, maxPixels: 1e9});
  var reduced_ndvi = ndvi.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: geom, scale: 9000, maxPixels: 1e9});
  var reduced_landc = landc.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: geom, scale: 9000, maxPixels: 1e9});
  var reduced_elev = elev.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: geom, scale: 9000, maxPixels: 1e9});
  var reduced_aslope = aslope.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: geom, scale: 9000, maxPixels: 1e9});
  var reduced_era5l = era5l.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: geom, scale: 9000, maxPixels: 1e9});
  
  final = final.set('soil_moisture_am', reduced_smam.get('soil_moisture_am'));
  final = final.set('ndvi', reduced_ndvi.get('NDVI'));
  final = final.set('longitude', ccords.get(0));
  final = final.set('latitude', ccords.get(1));
  final = final.set('month', initial_date.get('month'));
  final = final.set('day', initial_date.get('day'));
  final = final.set('land_cover', reduced_landc.get('LC_Prop1'));
  final = final.set('elevation', reduced_elev.get('be75'));
  final = final.set('aspect', reduced_aslope.get('aspect'));
  final = final.set('slope', reduced_aslope.get('slope'));
  final = final.set('dewpoint_temperature', reduced_era5l.get('dewpoint_temperature_2m'));
  final = final.set('skin_temperature', reduced_era5l.get('skin_temperature'));
  final = final.set('precipitation', reduced_era5l.get('total_precipitation_sum'));
  final = final.set('wind_u', reduced_era5l.get('u_component_of_wind_10m'));
  final = final.set('wind_v', reduced_era5l.get('v_component_of_wind_10m'));
  return final;
};
```

When I run the first `print(randoms.first())`, it compiles correctly. However, when I try to run it after mapping the "compute" function, it gives me the error: `Collection.first: Error in map(ID=31): Dictionary.get: Dictionary does not contain key: soil_moisture_am.` Peculiarly, this same function works perfectly when mapped onto another FeatureCollection containing polygons, and gives no errors.

What could be causing this error? (I have tried taking the average for upto 1 year back, and `.buffer(100000)`; however, this has not worked.)